# VBA setting the formula for a cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell, formula

I'm trying to set the formula for a cell using a (dynamically created) sheet name and a fixed cell address. I'm using the following line but can't seem to get it working:

```
"=" & strProjectName & "!" & Cells(2, 7).Address
```

Any advice on why this isn't working or a prod in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't try your formula, but as alternative you can always create a change event in a worksheet module and make the calculation programmatically.

Comment: What is an example value for `strProjectName`?  Are you trying to reference a worksheet or workbook that doesn't exist?

Comment: At that point it doesn't exist but a few lines later the sheet is created. Wouldn't think this would be an issue as when the macro finishes running; the sheet is in place

Comment: @Ryuu, that is your issue.  When you place that formula, Excel immediately tries to reference it.  When it can't find the workbook, it opens up the file browser so that you can pick a valid workbook.

Comment: @Stewbob, I was hoping that wasn't the problem. I'll try that now and get back to you.

Comment: @Stewbob, You were right. Feeling a little dumb at the moment but half expected it.
Could you create an Answer so I can mark it please

Comment: @Ryuu, already created one.

Comment: @Stewbob. My bad, just saw it. It's been a long day...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure what isn't working in your case, but the following code will put a formula into cell A1 that will retrieve the value in the cell G2.

```
strProjectName = "Sheet1"
Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=" & strProjectName & "!" & Cells(2, 7).Address
```

The workbook and worksheet that `strProjectName` references must exist at the time that this formula is placed.  Excel will immediately try to evaluate the formula.  You might be able to stop that from happening by turning off automatic recalculation until the workbook does exist.

Comment: That's what I've been doing but it doesn't resolve the formula - just shows #REF!
If it's any help, whenever I run the macro; it opens up a file browse dialogue box after passing that point in the code

Comment: @Ryuu, if it's asking for a filename, then the strProjectName is not pointing to a valid sheet name. A full reference for a formula is **[FileName]Sheetname!Address**. You can omit [Filename] for the current file, and you can omit [Filename]Sheetname for the current sheet, but those are the only combinations allowable in a cell reference

Comment: @Ryuu If your project name has a space in it you have to add a single quotemark before and after the project name.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
.Formula = "='" & strProjectName & "'!" & Cells(2, 7).Address
```

If your worksheet name (`strProjectName`) has spaces, you need to include the single quotes in the formula string.

If this does not resolve it, please provide more information about the specific error or failure.

**Update**

In comments you indicate you're replacing spaces with underscores.  Perhaps you are doing something like:

```
strProjectName = Replace(strProjectName," ", "_")
```

But if you're not also pushing that change to the `Worksheet.Name` property, you can expect these to happen:

1. The file browse dialog appears
2. The formula returns `#REF` error

The reason for both is that you are passing a reference to a worksheet that doesn't exist, which is why you get the #REF error.  The file dialog is an attempt to let you correct that reference, by pointing to a file wherein that sheet name **does** exist.  When you cancel out, the #REF error is expected.

So you need to do:

```
Worksheets(strProjectName).Name = Replace(strProjectName," ", "_")
strProjectName = Replace(strProjectName," ", "_")
```

Then, your formula should work.

Comment: I handle the space issue by replacing spaces with underscores. There's no error per se, it just doesn't resolve the formula (shows #REF!)
If it's any help, whenever I run the macro; it opens up a file browse dialogue box after passing that point in the code

Comment: If you're not also pushing the `REPLACE` function to the `Worksheet.Name` property, that is exactly what I'd expect to happen.  See revision above.

Comment: @Stewbob's comments above point you to the root cause of the error. Place the formula **after** the sheet has been created. then you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was just ordering. Rookie mistake but I've only been doing anything with macros for 2 days. Kind of expected that was the answer but was hoping it wasn't...

Answer (score 3):

If Cells(1, 1).Formula gives a 1004 error, like in my case, changes it to:

```
Cells(1, 1).FormulaLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make address directly, the worksheet must exist.

Turning off automatic recalculation want help you :)

But... you can get value indirectly...

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,7,1,0,""" & strProjectName & """),FALSE)"
```

At the time formula is inserted it will return #REF error, because strProjectName sheet does not exist.

But after this worksheet appear Excel will calculate formula again and proper value will be shown.

Disadvantage: there will be no tracking, so if you move the cell or change worksheet name, the formula will not adjust to the changes as in the direct addressing.