# Get back a formula from a cell - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm writing a VBA code, in which I need to reference in one sheet a formula from a different sheet
for instance: in sheet A in cell (1,3) there's a formula

```
"=R[-1]C*R[-2]C"
```

and I want in sheet B in cell (1, 3) to put the formula

```
"=A!R[-1]C*A!R[-2]C"
```

I want  to save in a string only the formula -

```
"=R[-1]C*R[-2]C"
```

And manually do the adjustments I need.

So my question is:

- How can I get the formula in the cell? when I write **`"temp=worksheets("A").cells(1,3)"`**,
  I get back the value from the cell, and not the formula...

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA setting the formula for a cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744537/vba-setting-the-formula-for-a-cell)

Comment: Did you find anything here useful? Did you test codes posted? You did not post ant feedback,

Answer (score 10):

You can get (and set) the formula in a cell (`A1` in this case) using, strangely enough:

```
Range("A1").Formula
```

(see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for details).

That just comes back as a string so you can evaluate/manipulate it with the regular VBA string functions like `left`, `right`, `mid`, `instr` and so on.

As per the linked page, the formula returned for a constant cell is just the constant itself, and a blank cell returns `""`.

You can use that information to decide if it's *actually* formulaic or not.

Comment: and if not all cells are formulas - and I want to change just the formulas?
is there some kind of "IsFormula" function?

Comment: @Bramat, updated with the relevant info, you can generally detect a formula by virtue of the fact it starts with `=`, anything else is a constant value of some description.

Comment: @Bramat  You can use the `HasFormula` property of the `Range` object

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("A")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("B")
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ws1.Range("C1")
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("C1")
Dim myf As String
myf = "=R[-1]C*R[-2]C"
rng1.FormulaR1C1 = myf  ' The property you were asking about
```

Adapt it as needed.
Note the use of variables to refer to `Range`s.