# Converting a "RC" format to "A1" - Excel formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a VBA code, in which I need to reference in one sheet a formula from a different sheet for instance: in sheet A in cell (1,3) there's a formula

```
"=RC[-1]*RC[-2]"
```

and I want in sheet B in cell (1, 3) to put the formula

```
"=A!RC[-1]*A!RC[-2]"
```

when I write

```
"Temp = Worksheets("A").Cells(1,3).Value"
```

I get

```
"Temp = B1*A1"
```

In my sheet I work in "RC" format, but the `VBA returns a "A1" format`...

How can I retrieve it in the format I use? or convert the formula I get to a "RC" format?

Comment: Please clarify your question and show your actual code.  What you have written doesn't make sense.  If the contents of `R1C3` is the formula in quotes, then Temp will contain that formula.  If the formula is NOT in quotes, then Temp will contain the results of the formula.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get back a formula from a cell - VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899507/get-back-a-formula-from-a-cell-vba)

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I retrieve it in the format I use? or convert the formula I get to a "RC" format?*

You retrieve the formula in the `R1C1` format by using the `FormulaR1C1` property of the `Range` object.  This will be true no matter what reference style you are using.

If need be, you can retrieve the reference style you are using with the `ReferenceStyle` property of the `Application` object.

As I wrote in my comment, the rest of your question needs clarification.

Comment: I got the formula right, and made the adjustmens I needed.
now I have in Temp "=IF(A!RC[1]="~","~","")", and when I write "cells(1, 3) = Temp", temp contains "=IF(A!R[-2]C[470]="~","~","")"

It's making me crazy - I've tried removing the "=" and putting "=" & the formula, nothing works...
how do i fix it?

Comment: @Bramat As I have indicated previously, clarify and show your **actual code**.  This is best done by editing your Question so it can be legibly formatted. Don't bother writing your actual code into a comment