# Openpyxl - Copy range of cells(with formula) from a workbook to another

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to copy specific rows from Workbook 1 and append it to the existing data in Workbook 2.

Copy the highlighed rows from 
[Workbook 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPhG5.png),
and append them in [Workbook 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2ogq.png) below 'March'

So far I succeeded to copy and paste the range, but there are two problems:

1.Cells are a shifted

2.The percentage(formula) is missing, leaving only numeric values.

[See Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3h5W.png)

```
import openpyxl as xl

source = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Test_project_20200401.xlsx"
wbs = xl.load_workbook(source)
wbs_sheet = wbs["P2"] #selecting the sheet

destination = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Try999.xlsx"
wbd = xl.load_workbook(destination)
wbd_sheet = wbd["A3"] #select the sheet

row_data = 0

for row in wbs_sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "Yes":
            row_data += cell.row

for row in wbs_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=row_data, min_col = 1, max_col=250, max_row = row_data+1):
    wbd_sheet.append((cell.value for cell in row))            


wbd.save(destination)
```

Does anyone have any idea on how can I solve this? 
Any feedback/solution would help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to add my own solution in here.

What I did, was to iterate through the columns and apply "cell.number_format = '0%', which converts your cell value to percentage.

```
for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=2, max_row=250, max_col=250):
    for cell in col:
        cell.number_format = '0%'
```

More info can be found in here:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html

Answer (score 1):

I think **min_col** should **= 0**

**Range("A1").Formula** (in VBA) gets the formula.
Range("A1").Value (in VBA) gets the value.

So try using .formula in Python

(thanks to:  [Get back a formula from a cell - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899507/get-back-a-formula-from-a-cell-vba) ... if this works)