# Export a List&Label table with formula to Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, listlabel

I have an existing List&Label report containing a table with three columns:

```
col1 = valueA
col2 = valueB
col3 = valueA + valueB
```

When exporting these list to excel, the resulting excel table contains only values in all three columns.

Example export:

[image]

I tried to enter the formula for col3 as text, but then Excel also interpreted it as text.

[image]

Is there a way to export the table with List&Label to Excel, so that I have a working formula in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately - no. As List & Label has its own formula language that isnt't entirely translateable to Excel, there is no layer for this purpose - all values are exported as is. I'd export just columns A and B and add the formula to the resulting sheet. If this is something you need to do often/automatically, you could use VBA to post process the sheet. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744537/vba-setting-the-formula-for-a-cell) is a primer how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to List & Label and I'm evaluating it currently for further use. While my research to the product I found this article which describes new feature within the export format to Excel and meanwhile formulas are supported in the latest version - look there: [Generating Excel Formulas in Worksheets](https://www.combit.blog/en/excel-export-list-label-28/)

Comment: You should check out [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide, specifically "Provide context for links" part.

Comment: The answer should have been a comment, but otherwise this is perfectly correct information.

Comment: @Aarlaneth Thank you for the hint writing my answer/comment correct - i'm also new to stackoverflow as you can see and there seems a lot to lern for me.