# vba hyperlink and data coping from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

i have a workbook that i am working in. i have most of it working the way that i want right now. the area that i am having difficulty with is in the code below.

```
Private Sub newITEMsheet_Click()

    ' newROWmainPAGE Macro
    ' insert new row on the part number list

    Dim MySheetName As Variant    
    MySheetName = Application.InputBox("Which part number would you like to add to the list?")

    If MySheetName = "" Then Exit Sub
    If MySheetName = False Then Exit Sub
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A3").Value = MySheetName
    Range("q1").Value = MySheetName
    Sheets("blank").Copy After:=Sheets("blank")


    ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName
    ActiveSheet.[c1] = ActiveSheet.Name


 End Sub
```

what i am trying to achieve is:
the user clicks a button that says add new part number
then get a input box. inputbox value is a variable
when that is done it inserts a row above row 3, inserts stored variable into cells a3 and q1.
it then copies "blank" worksheet {it is not truly blank} and inserts it as a new sheet after blank. 
the new active sheet then has a name change to the variable. 
it also inserts the variable into cell c1.
this is all working good.

the part that i need help with is having cell a3 on the original workrksheet become a hyperlink to the new worksheet.
i also need to have information that is in cell c2 on the new worksheet be linked over to cell b3 on the original. it must be linked in a manor that if the info on the second sheet changes so does it on the first.

Comment: So... you are wanting to [Create a hyperlink to another sheet in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813488/excel-vba-create-hyperlink-to-another-sheet) and [set a formula for a cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744537/vba-setting-the-formula-for-a-cell) ?

Comment: Both parts of the questions @JNevill links to appear to resolve the problem, or should at least get you started. Can you try to implement those solutions, and if you have a problem implementing one (or both) of those, then edit your question with the specific issue(s) you're having. Cheers.